# Laravel - DELETE Ajax request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, destroy

I am using Laravel 5.0. I have created a RESTful Controller. Now i wanna use the destroy function via an ajax call.
This is my JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type:   'POST',
    url:    '/pv/' + data.id,
    data:   {_method: 'delete' },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And this is my destroy function:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $pv = PV::find($id);

    $pv->delete();

    return true;
}
```

All i got is a 500 error.

Comment: Change `type: 'POST'` to `type:'DELETE'`

Comment: @FabioAntunes Didn't worked for me.

Comment: Check the laravel error log in `storage/logs`

Comment: can you put a var_dump inside your destroy? just to check if you are calling it? also are you sure that the route is set? try doing a `php artisan route:list` and check if that route exists

Comment: there is nothing in the laravel error log, cause it is a server 500 error.
@FabioAntunes yes the route exist.

Answer (score 4):

first check your route in laravel

```
Route::delete('/deleteprocess', 'Controller@destroy');
```

in javascript

```
$.ajax({
url: '/deleteprocess',
type: 'POST',
data:{
'_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr("content"),
'_method': 'DELETE',
 },
success: function(result) {
    // Do something with the result
}});
```

set type : POST, 
set token : _token, 
set method : _method as DELETE,

Answer (score 2):

That's probabily a "CSRF" Exception. If you are using Ajax Request with jQuery, add this (before your `$.ajax`):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

And, in your "html" ..create a new "meta tag" with csrf-token..value:

```
{{ csrf_token() }}
```

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection